# Compress files from a directory in gzip format (*.gz)

Tags: r

I have a directory that contains files with different file extensions and I have to compress them one by one because the 7z program does not allow me to do it massively. for Example:

- List item
- file1.xyz
- file2.rrr
- file3.qwe
- file250.pep

expected output

- file1.xyz.gz
- file2.rrr.gz
- file3.qwe.gz
- file250.pep.gz

any idea how to do this in R? thank you

Comment: this seems to be a usage question, and also unrelated to [tag:r]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this in R. Assuming your files are in a subdirectory called `files`:

```r
files  <- dir("./files/", full.names = TRUE)
lapply(files, R.utils::gzip, remove = FALSE)
```

Note that `remove = FALSE` is very important if after compression you do not want to delete the original file. The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R.utils/versions/1.7.5/topics/gzip) lists other options, e.g. whether you want to overwrite existing files of the same name.